# problem with calculating mean absolute percentage error on a weekly basis in R

Tags: r, mean, percentage, absolute

I have a large time series of actual and forecasted electricity generation values for each quarter of the hour, that looks like this:

```
    df<-structure(list(DATETIME = structure(c(1604188800, 1604189700, 
1604190600, 1604191500, 1604192400, 1604193300, 1604194200, 1604195100, 
1604196000, 1604196900, 1604197800, 1604198700, 1604199600, 1604200500, 
1604201400, 1604202300, 1604203200, 1604204100, 1604205000, 1604205900, 
1604206800, 1604207700, 1604208600, 1604209500, 1604210400, 1604211300, 
1604212200, 1604213100, 1604214000, 1604214900, 1604215800, 1604216700, 
1604217600, 1604218500, 1604219400, 1604220300, 1604221200, 1604222100, 
1604223000, 1604223900, 1604224800, 1604225700, 1604226600, 1604227500, 
1604228400, 1604229300, 1604230200, 1604231100, 1604232000, 1604232900, 
1604233800, 1604234700, 1604235600, 1604236500, 1604237400, 1604238300, 
1604239200, 1604240100, 1604241000, 1604241900, 1604242800, 1604243700, 
1604244600, 1604245500, 1604246400, 1604247300, 1604248200, 1604249100, 
1604250000, 1604250900, 1604251800, 1604252700, 1604253600, 1604254500, 
1604255400, 1604256300, 1604257200, 1604258100, 1604259000, 1604259900, 
1604260800, 1604261700, 1604262600, 1604263500, 1604264400, 1604265300, 
1604266200, 1604267100, 1604268000, 1604268900, 1604269800, 1604270700, 
1604271600, 1604272500, 1604273400, 1604274300, 1604275200, 1604276100, 
1604277000, 1604277900, 1604278800, 1604279700, 1604280600, 1604281500, 
1604282400, 1604283300, 1604284200, 1604285100, 1604286000, 1604286900, 
1604287800, 1604288700, 1604289600, 1604290500, 1604291400, 1604292300, 
1604293200, 1604294100, 1604295000, 1604295900, 1604296800, 1604297700, 
1604298600, 1604299500, 1604300400, 1604301300, 1604302200, 1604303100, 
1604304000, 1604304900, 1604305800, 1604306700, 1604307600, 1604308500, 
1604309400, 1604310300, 1604311200, 1604312100, 1604313000, 1604313900, 
1604314800, 1604315700, 1604316600, 1604317500, 1604318400, 1604319300, 
1604320200, 1604321100, 1604322000, 1604322900, 1604323800, 1604324700, 
1604325600, 1604326500, 1604327400, 1604328300, 1604329200, 1604330100, 
1604331000, 1604331900, 1604332800, 1604333700, 1604334600, 1604335500, 
1604336400, 1604337300, 1604338200, 1604339100, 1604340000, 1604340900, 
1604341800, 1604342700, 1604343600, 1604344500, 1604345400, 1604346300, 
1604347200, 1604348100, 1604349000, 1604349900, 1604350800, 1604351700, 
1604352600, 1604353500, 1604354400, 1604355300, 1604356200, 1604357100, 
1604358000, 1604358900, 1604359800, 1604360700, 1604361600, 1604362500, 
1604363400, 1604364300, 1604365200, 1604366100, 1604367000, 1604367900, 
1604368800, 1604369700, 1604370600, 1604371500, 1604372400, 1604373300, 
1604374200, 1604375100, 1604376000, 1604376900, 1604377800, 1604378700, 
1604379600, 1604380500, 1604381400, 1604382300, 1604383200, 1604384100, 
1604385000, 1604385900, 1604386800, 1604387700, 1604388600, 1604389500, 
1604390400, 1604391300, 1604392200, 1604393100, 1604394000, 1604394900, 
1604395800, 1604396700, 1604397600, 1604398500, 1604399400, 1604400300, 
1604401200, 1604402100, 1604403000, 1604403900, 1604404800, 1604405700, 
1604406600, 1604407500, 1604408400, 1604409300, 1604410200, 1604411100, 
1604412000, 1604412900, 1604413800, 1604414700, 1604415600, 1604416500, 
1604417400, 1604418300, 1604419200, 1604420100, 1604421000, 1604421900, 
1604422800, 1604423700, 1604424600, 1604425500, 1604426400, 1604427300, 
1604428200, 1604429100, 1604430000, 1604430900, 1604431800, 1604432700, 
1604433600, 1604434500, 1604435400, 1604436300, 1604437200, 1604438100, 
1604439000, 1604439900, 1604440800, 1604441700, 1604442600, 1604443500, 
1604444400, 1604445300, 1604446200, 1604447100, 1604448000, 1604448900, 
1604449800, 1604450700, 1604451600, 1604452500, 1604453400, 1604454300, 
1604455200, 1604456100, 1604457000, 1604457900, 1604458800, 1604459700, 
1604460600, 1604461500, 1604462400, 1604463300, 1604464200, 1604465100, 
1604466000, 1604466900, 1604467800, 1604468700, 1604469600, 1604470500, 
1604471400, 1604472300, 1604473200, 1604474100, 1604475000, 1604475900, 
1604476800, 1604477700, 1604478600, 1604479500, 1604480400, 1604481300, 
1604482200, 1604483100, 1604484000, 1604484900, 1604485800, 1604486700, 
1604487600, 1604488500, 1604489400, 1604490300, 1604491200, 1604492100, 
1604493000, 1604493900, 1604494800, 1604495700, 1604496600, 1604497500, 
1604498400, 1604499300, 1604500200, 1604501100, 1604502000, 1604502900, 
1604503800, 1604504700, 1604505600, 1604506500, 1604507400, 1604508300, 
1604509200, 1604510100, 1604511000, 1604511900, 1604512800, 1604513700, 
1604514600, 1604515500, 1604516400, 1604517300, 1604518200, 1604519100, 
1604520000, 1604520900, 1604521800, 1604522700, 1604523600, 1604524500, 
1604525400, 1604526300, 1604527200, 1604528100, 1604529000, 1604529900, 
1604530800, 1604531700, 1604532600, 1604533500, 1604534400, 1604535300, 
1604536200, 1604537100, 1604538000, 1604538900, 1604539800, 1604540700, 
1604541600, 1604542500, 1604543400, 1604544300, 1604545200, 1604546100, 
1604547000, 1604547900, 1604548800, 1604549700, 1604550600, 1604551500, 
1604552400, 1604553300, 1604554200, 1604555100, 1604556000, 1604556900, 
1604557800, 1604558700, 1604559600, 1604560500, 1604561400, 1604562300, 
1604563200, 1604564100, 1604565000, 1604565900, 1604566800, 1604567700, 
1604568600, 1604569500, 1604570400, 1604571300, 1604572200, 1604573100, 
1604574000, 1604574900, 1604575800, 1604576700, 1604577600, 1604578500, 
1604579400, 1604580300, 1604581200, 1604582100, 1604583000, 1604583900, 
1604584800, 1604585700, 1604586600, 1604587500, 1604588400, 1604589300, 
1604590200, 1604591100, 1604592000, 1604592900, 1604593800, 1604594700, 
1604595600, 1604596500, 1604597400, 1604598300, 1604599200, 1604600100, 
1604601000, 1604601900, 1604602800, 1604603700, 1604604600, 1604605500, 
1604606400, 1604607300, 1604608200, 1604609100, 1604610000, 1604610900, 
1604611800, 1604612700, 1604613600, 1604614500, 1604615400, 1604616300, 
1604617200, 1604618100, 1604619000, 1604619900, 1604620800, 1604621700, 
1604622600, 1604623500, 1604624400, 1604625300, 1604626200, 1604627100, 
1604628000, 1604628900, 1604629800, 1604630700, 1604631600, 1604632500, 
1604633400, 1604634300, 1604635200, 1604636100, 1604637000, 1604637900, 
1604638800, 1604639700, 1604640600, 1604641500, 1604642400, 1604643300, 
1604644200, 1604645100, 1604646000, 1604646900, 1604647800, 1604648700, 
1604649600, 1604650500, 1604651400, 1604652300, 1604653200, 1604654100, 
1604655000, 1604655900, 1604656800, 1604657700, 1604658600, 1604659500, 
1604660400, 1604661300, 1604662200, 1604663100, 1604664000, 1604664900, 
1604665800, 1604666700, 1604667600, 1604668500, 1604669400, 1604670300, 
1604671200, 1604672100, 1604673000, 1604673900, 1604674800, 1604675700, 
1604676600, 1604677500, 1604678400, 1604679300, 1604680200, 1604681100, 
1604682000, 1604682900, 1604683800, 1604684700, 1604685600, 1604686500, 
1604687400, 1604688300, 1604689200, 1604690100, 1604691000, 1604691900, 
1604692800, 1604693700, 1604694600, 1604695500, 1604696400, 1604697300, 
1604698200, 1604699100, 1604700000, 1604700900, 1604701800, 1604702700, 
1604703600, 1604704500, 1604705400, 1604706300, 1604707200, 1604708100, 
1604709000, 1604709900, 1604710800, 1604711700, 1604712600, 1604713500, 
1604714400, 1604715300, 1604716200, 1604717100, 1604718000, 1604718900, 
1604719800, 1604720700, 1604721600, 1604722500, 1604723400, 1604724300, 
1604725200, 1604726100, 1604727000, 1604727900, 1604728800, 1604729700, 
1604730600, 1604731500, 1604732400, 1604733300, 1604734200, 1604735100, 
1604736000, 1604736900, 1604737800, 1604738700, 1604739600, 1604740500, 
1604741400, 1604742300, 1604743200, 1604744100, 1604745000, 1604745900, 
1604746800, 1604747700, 1604748600, 1604749500, 1604750400, 1604751300, 
1604752200, 1604753100, 1604754000, 1604754900, 1604755800, 1604756700, 
1604757600, 1604758500, 1604759400, 1604760300, 1604761200, 1604762100, 
1604763000, 1604763900, 1604764800, 1604765700, 1604766600, 1604767500, 
1604768400, 1604769300, 1604770200, 1604771100, 1604772000, 1604772900, 
1604773800, 1604774700, 1604775600, 1604776500, 1604777400, 1604778300, 
1604779200, 1604780100, 1604781000, 1604781900, 1604782800, 1604783700, 
1604784600, 1604785500, 1604786400, 1604787300, 1604788200, 1604789100, 
1604790000, 1604790900, 1604791800, 1604792700), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Actual = c(5.718, 5.844, 5.971, 5.925, 
5.414, 5.432, 5.521, 5.513, 5.524, 6.182, 6.947, 7.133, 7.746, 
7.058, 6.615, 9.665, 12.015, 12.029, 11.957, 12.981, 16.03, 16.821, 
16.897, 15.383, 14.029, 14.642, 10.721, 9.187, 8.466, 6.89, 5.916, 
7.977, 11.577, 12.432, 14.191, 14.655, 16.77, 17.376, 16.656, 
16.659, 16.249, 15.771, 15.969, 15.623, 14.488, 14.506, 14.37, 
13.399, 11.806, 10.78, 9.962, 10.093, 8.922, 10.099, 9.832, 8.406, 
7.077, 6.514, 5.942, 6.502, 5.731, 5.276, 7.513, 7.141, 6.74, 
6.36, 7.061, 8.619, 8.845, 9.808, 9.702, 10.079, 8.703, 7.287, 
7.239, 7.768, 7.338, 7.11, 6.975, 7.35, 6.209, 6.441, 6.641, 
5.892, 5.148, 4.533, 4.223, 3.89, 3.498, 2.941, 3.06, 3.244, 
3.521, 3.703, 3.314, 3.507, 3.705, 3.073, 2.472, 2.344, 2.695, 
2.729, 2.652, 2.582, 2.731, 2.759, 2.866, 3.283, 3.138, 3.009, 
3.126, 3.389, 3.205, 3.39, 3.942, 4.029, 4.186, 4.282, 4.335, 
4.026, 3.863, 3.772, 3.25, 3.282, 3.332, 3.18, 2.929, 3.054, 
3.579, 3.886, 3.145, 2.984, 3.305, 3.535, 3.59, 4.079, 4.141, 
3.957, 3.786, 3.505, 3.101, 2.892, 2.501, 2.243, 2.151, 1.96, 
1.907, 1.911, 1.901, 1.96, 1.854, 1.88, 2.25, 2.252, 2.154, 2.11, 
2.081, 2.27, 2.545, 2.864, 2.854, 3.257, 3.8, 4.158, 3.732, 3.771, 
4.19, 4.964, 4.323, 5.286, 4.407, 4.795, 5.225, 5.726, 5.732, 
5.836, 6.799, 6.322, 6.262, 5.851, 5.172, 5.007, 5.641, 5.812, 
4.964, 4.531, 5.07, 5.403, 5.176, 5.122, 5.618, 6.368, 5.941, 
6.191, 6.094, 6.703, 6.977, 6.391, 6.664, 6.671, 6.65, 6.687, 
7.659, 8.364, 8.088, 7.329, 7.634, 7.981, 8.941, 8.922, 8.898, 
8.921, 8.65, 9.39, 8.253, 7.656, 7.588, 6.226, 5.269, 4.915, 
4.918, 4.594, 4.873, 4.414, 4.384, 3.967, 3.432, 3.287, 3.48, 
3.374, 3.476, 4.54, 6.395, 6.67, 6.094, 5.212, 5.289, 4.99, 4.113, 
3.32, 3.09, 2.25, 2.42, 2.812, 2.544, 2.466, 2.892, 3.04, 2.665, 
2.303, 2.162, 1.896, 1.704, 1.683, 1.788, 1.841, 2.162, 2.288, 
2.108, 1.943, 1.582, 1.347, 1.256, 1.301, 1.649, 1.615, 1.669, 
1.855, 1.952, 2.354, 2.513, 2.314, 2.314, 2.623, 2.646, 2.655, 
2.795, 2.829, 3.225, 3.759, 4.926, 6.119, 6.206, 6.608, 6.237, 
5.74, 6.116, 8.257, 9.366, 9.073, 8.124, 6.595, 5, 4.428, 4.25, 
4.662, 6.04, 7.415, 6.713, 6.646, 6.287, 6.502, 6.023, 5.789, 
6.211, 7.477, 8.396, 9.687, 11.208, 9.911, 9.085, 8.758, 8.411, 
8.321, 8.393, 8.796, 9.682, 9.908, 9.637, 10.39, 11.094, 12.521, 
15.086, 14.875, 15.56, 15.396, 15.365, 16.238, 17.188, 17.16, 
17.902, 15.802, 14.354, 12.045, 11.883, 12.716, 13.031, 11.346, 
12.645, 13.082, 14.082, 14.606, 15.297, 15.215, 14.762, 15.61, 
17.65, 17.997, 17.933, 17.884, 17.323, 17.169, 19.862, 23.073, 
25.928, 27.872, 28.236, 30.207, 29.643, 28.742, 28.017, 25.973, 
26.97, 28.061, 26.099, 25.133, 23.174, 20.483, 19.969, 21.094, 
23.736, 26.382, 29.764, 33.129, 36.769, 38.491, 35.788, 35.61, 
37.34, 35.794, 35.368, 34.635, 33.84, 33.404, 32.614, 30.159, 
32.87, 33.89, 34.26, 33.309, 34.895, 34.596, 35.942, 37.642, 
38.688, 39.047, 39.552, 40.228, 41.329, 42.208, 43.073, 41.838, 
40.083, 40.6, 41.215, 41.782, 41.454, 41.65, 42.493, 42.297, 
42.925, 43.51, 42.537, 42.897, 42.832, 42.54, 43.833, 44.497, 
43.118, 42.778, 41.69, 40.37, 40.367, 43.267, 44.982, 46.84, 
46.205, 46.376, 43.302, 40.977, 41.712, 42.041, 42.881, 43.467, 
43.469, 45.591, 42.482, 45.196, 44.643, 43.234, 43.791, 45.037, 
44.114, 43.488, 42.825, 41.382, 41.102, 39.78, 40.251, 40.823, 
41.788, 43.272, 42.782, 41.288, 42.616, 44.222, 47.462, 48.783, 
48.18, 48.067, 47.608, 46.76, 49.739, 47.404, 47.416, 44.787, 
46.945, 49.951, 51.052, 50.017, 51.615, 51.965, 53.686, 54.802, 
57.408, 57.979, 57.367, 57.363, 53.659, 50.096, 47.254, 43.275, 
43.44, 42.811, 43.405, 47.903, 51.26, 52.405, 55.277, 54.637, 
54.626, 54.327, 53.697, 53.366, 54.955, 52.65, 51.526, 52.107, 
53.781, 50.12, 51.497, 54.426, 55.57, 54.662, 50.37, 54.62, 58.996, 
60.24, 57.378, 56.576, 56.589, 58.439, 59.768, 59.263, 56.691, 
59.286, 59.953, 60.097, 55.379, 49.2, 46.915, 52.828, 53.813, 
52.989, 53.829, 53.209, 54.683, 55.321, 56.154, 55.016, 54.061, 
53.296, 53.772, 52.342, 51.84, 52.607, 53.034, 54.727, 55.591, 
54.567, 53.198, 50.51, 49.453, 49.908, 48.499, 47.923, 49.602, 
48.64, 51.539, 52.353, 51.426, 50.687, 48.629, 46.685, 48.598, 
48.944, 48.143, 46.887, 47.518, 46.229, 45.746, 46.078, 47.155, 
46.933, 49.07, 49.243, 48.567, 48.352, 48.28, 48.954, 49.512, 
48.704, 49.681, 50.053, 50.957, 49.603, 47.978, 50, 50.963, 50.415, 
50.266, 50.155, 50.662, 51.918, 53.166, 52.792, 54.156, 55.07, 
53.702, 54.07, 54.098, 54.46, 53.783, 54.023, 53.997, 55.079, 
54.819, 54.935, 53.642, 54.181, 54.903, 56.18, 56.016, 55.307, 
53.558, 52.03, 54.562, 58.919, 58.351, 57.536, 59.128, 60.585, 
60.938, 60.858, 60.539, 59.114, 57.326, 58.094, 58.355, 58.507, 
57.85, 55.829, 57.801, 59.946, 58.755, 56.767, 55.223, 55.452, 
58.029, 60.207, 60.816, 60.403, 59.365, 58.132, 57.989, 59.469, 
58.991, 58.748, 58.43, 57.926, 58.671, 58.192, 58.335, 58.222, 
58.802, 58.458, 58.537, 59.014, 59.015, 57.656, 56.055, 53.788, 
54.659, 53.911, 54.722, 56.387, 57.327, 57.251, 57.596, 56.207, 
54.747, 53.934, 55.108, 55.669, 57.554, 57.824, 56.961, 54.605, 
54.705, 54.599, 54.044, 53.627), Forecasted = c(4.843, 4.843, 
4.843, 4.843, 3.695, 3.695, 3.695, 3.695, 3.313, 3.313, 3.313, 
3.313, 3.198, 3.198, 3.198, 3.198, 3.74, 3.74, 3.74, 3.74, 5.115, 
5.115, 5.115, 5.115, 7.01, 7.01, 7.01, 7.01, 9.236, 9.236, 9.236, 
9.236, 16.695, 16.695, 16.695, 16.695, 28.66, 28.66, 28.66, 28.66, 
34.778, 34.778, 34.778, 34.778, 35.03, 35.03, 35.03, 35.03, 32.805, 
32.805, 32.805, 32.805, 28.593, 28.593, 28.593, 28.593, 22.283, 
22.283, 22.283, 22.283, 19.164, 19.164, 19.164, 19.164, 17.839, 
17.839, 17.839, 17.839, 15.454, 15.454, 15.454, 15.454, 12.195, 
12.195, 12.195, 12.195, 8.568, 8.568, 8.568, 8.568, 7.477, 7.477, 
7.477, 7.477, 6.314, 6.314, 6.314, 6.314, 5.763, 5.763, 5.763, 
5.763, 4.615, 4.615, 4.615, 4.615, 3.57, 3.57, 3.57, 3.57, 3.438, 
3.438, 3.438, 3.438, 3.618, 3.618, 3.618, 3.618, 2.983, 2.983, 
2.983, 2.983, 2.513, 2.513, 2.513, 2.513, 2.075, 2.075, 2.075, 
2.075, 2.015, 2.015, 2.015, 2.015, 2.315, 2.315, 2.315, 2.315, 
2.325, 2.325, 2.325, 2.325, 2.363, 2.363, 2.363, 2.363, 2.058, 
2.058, 2.058, 2.058, 1.455, 1.455, 1.455, 1.455, 1.878, 1.878, 
1.878, 1.878, 2.165, 2.165, 2.165, 2.165, 2.633, 2.633, 2.633, 
2.633, 3.279, 3.279, 3.279, 3.279, 2.935, 2.935, 2.935, 2.935, 
2.833, 2.833, 2.833, 2.833, 2.89, 2.89, 2.89, 2.89, 3.952, 3.952, 
3.952, 3.952, 4.037, 4.037, 4.037, 4.037, 4.311, 4.311, 4.311, 
4.311, 4.242, 4.242, 4.242, 4.242, 2.478, 2.478, 2.478, 2.478, 
6.285, 6.285, 6.285, 6.285, 6.803, 6.803, 6.803, 6.803, 7.54, 
7.54, 7.54, 7.54, 8.383, 8.383, 8.383, 8.383, 8.86, 8.86, 8.86, 
8.86, 8.65, 8.65, 8.65, 8.65, 8.11, 8.11, 8.11, 8.11, 7.783, 
7.783, 7.783, 7.783, 6.995, 6.995, 6.995, 6.995, 5.98, 5.98, 
5.98, 5.98, 5.22, 5.22, 5.22, 5.22, 5.023, 5.023, 5.023, 5.023, 
7.343, 7.343, 7.343, 7.343, 7.29, 7.29, 7.29, 7.29, 7.315, 7.315, 
7.315, 7.315, 7.63, 7.63, 7.63, 7.63, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 7.875, 
7.993, 7.993, 7.993, 7.993, 5.315, 5.315, 5.315, 5.315, 5.787, 
5.787, 5.787, 5.787, 5.097, 5.097, 5.097, 5.097, 6.878, 6.878, 
6.878, 6.878, 6.337, 6.337, 6.337, 6.337, 4.025, 4.025, 4.025, 
4.025, 2.665, 2.665, 2.665, 2.665, 4.573, 4.573, 4.573, 4.573, 
6.248, 6.248, 6.248, 6.248, 5.534, 5.534, 5.534, 5.534, 6.268, 
6.268, 6.268, 6.268, 5.964, 5.964, 5.964, 5.964, 5.23, 5.23, 
5.23, 5.23, 7.155, 7.155, 7.155, 7.155, 9.775, 9.775, 9.775, 
9.775, 12.565, 12.565, 12.565, 12.565, 11.868, 11.868, 11.868, 
11.868, 11.473, 11.473, 11.473, 11.473, 10.698, 10.698, 10.698, 
10.698, 12.933, 12.933, 12.933, 12.933, 13.148, 13.148, 13.148, 
13.148, 12.845, 12.845, 12.845, 12.845, 11.588, 11.588, 11.588, 
11.588, 16.374, 16.374, 16.374, 16.374, 19.543, 19.543, 19.543, 
19.543, 21.938, 21.938, 21.938, 21.938, 22.425, 22.425, 22.425, 
22.425, 22.738, 22.738, 22.738, 22.738, 28.695, 28.695, 28.695, 
28.695, 29.352, 29.352, 29.352, 29.352, 34.76, 34.76, 34.76, 
34.76, 31.81, 31.81, 31.81, 31.81, 33.791, 33.791, 33.791, 33.791, 
35.23, 35.23, 35.23, 35.23, 35.308, 35.308, 35.308, 35.308, 35.13, 
35.13, 35.13, 35.13, 37.11, 37.11, 37.11, 37.11, 37.073, 37.073, 
37.073, 37.073, 40.596, 40.596, 40.596, 40.596, 40.7, 40.7, 40.7, 
40.7, 45.062, 45.062, 45.062, 45.062, 43.892, 43.892, 43.892, 
43.892, 44.33, 44.33, 44.33, 44.33, 42.638, 42.638, 42.638, 42.638, 
45.95, 45.95, 45.95, 45.95, 50.997, 50.997, 50.997, 50.997, 50.458, 
50.458, 50.458, 50.458, 49.61, 49.61, 49.61, 49.61, 50.95, 50.95, 
50.95, 50.95, 49.273, 49.273, 49.273, 49.273, 46.993, 46.993, 
46.993, 46.993, 47.368, 47.368, 47.368, 47.368, 48.526, 48.526, 
48.526, 48.526, 51.974, 51.974, 51.974, 51.974, 61.343, 61.343, 
61.343, 61.343, 61.38, 61.38, 61.38, 61.38, 61.763, 61.763, 61.763, 
61.763, 61.96, 61.96, 61.96, 61.96, 59.295, 59.295, 59.295, 59.295, 
59.98, 59.98, 59.98, 59.98, 59.233, 59.233, 59.233, 59.233, 56.633, 
56.633, 56.633, 56.633, 57.81, 57.81, 57.81, 57.81, 63.66, 63.66, 
63.66, 63.66, 67.34, 67.34, 67.34, 67.34, 67.59, 67.59, 67.59, 
67.59, 68.453, 68.453, 68.453, 68.453, 66.291, 66.291, 66.291, 
66.291, 62.495, 62.495, 62.495, 62.495, 61.142, 61.142, 61.142, 
61.142, 51.96, 51.96, 51.96, 51.96, 48.465, 48.465, 48.465, 48.465, 
51.932, 51.932, 51.932, 51.932, 54.498, 54.498, 54.498, 54.498, 
56.787, 56.787, 56.787, 56.787, 58.053, 58.053, 58.053, 58.053, 
57.649, 57.649, 57.649, 57.649, 54.156, 54.156, 54.156, 54.156, 
39.908, 39.908, 39.908, 39.908, 40.138, 40.138, 40.138, 40.138, 
41.303, 41.303, 41.303, 41.303, 41.175, 41.175, 41.175, 41.175, 
39.023, 39.023, 39.023, 39.023, 39.09, 39.09, 39.09, 39.09, 39.238, 
39.238, 39.238, 39.238, 44.308, 44.308, 44.308, 44.308, 41.595, 
41.595, 41.595, 41.595, 45.503, 45.503, 45.503, 45.503, 45.773, 
45.773, 45.773, 45.773, 46.703, 46.703, 46.703, 46.703, 51.37, 
51.37, 51.37, 51.37, 50.908, 50.908, 50.908, 50.908, 46.036, 
46.036, 46.036, 46.036, 43.526, 43.526, 43.526, 43.526, 38.05, 
38.05, 38.05, 38.05, 34.29, 34.29, 34.29, 34.29, 34.306, 34.306, 
34.306, 34.306, 37.668, 37.668, 37.668, 37.668, 41.563, 41.563, 
41.563, 41.563, 41.171, 41.171, 41.171, 41.171, 42.225, 42.225, 
42.225, 42.225, 43.463, 43.463, 43.463, 43.463)), row.names = c(NA, 
672L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to calculate the mean absolute percentage error for each (calendar) week of the dataset and I have tried several ways, such as the function apply.weekly, but none of them seems to work.

```
apply.weekly(df, function(x) mean(abs((df$Actual-df$Forecasted)/df$Actual)))
```

I keep getting as outcome the same value for each quarter of the dataset, and not an outcome for each week.
Do you have any ideas on how to implement this calculation?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: your sample is one day only.  I suggest include at least two weeks to demonstrate.

Comment: Each day has 96 quarters, that would mean 1.344 rows.

Comment: So, a few rows only for 2-3 weeks may serve the purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps like so:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

df %>% group_by( isoweek( DATETIME ), year( DATETIME ) ) %>%
    summarise( DateCount = n_distinct(date(DATETIME)), MeanError = mean( abs(Forecasted-Actual)/Actual ) )
```

It outputs:

```
  `isoweek(DATETIME)` `year(DATETIME)` DateCount MeanError
                <dbl>            <dbl>     <int>     <dbl>
1                  44             2020         1     0.858
2                  45             2020         6     0.357
```

With the updated data source:

```r
df <- read.delim( "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Argiro1983/data-set/main/test1", sep=";" ) %>%
    as_tibble

df %<>% mutate( DATETIME = dmy_hm(DATETIME) )

df %>% group_by( year( DATETIME ), isoweek( DATETIME )  ) %>%
    summarise( DateCount = n_distinct(date(DATETIME)), MeanError = mean( abs(Forecasted-Actual)/Actual ) )
```

Output:

```
   `year(DATETIME)` `isoweek(DATETIME)` DateCount MeanError
              <dbl>               <dbl>     <int>     <dbl>
 1             2020                  44         1     0.858
 2             2020                  45         7     0.321
 3             2020                  46         7     0.505
 4             2020                  47         7     0.439
 5             2020                  48         7     0.309
 6             2020                  49         7     0.545
 7             2020                  50         7     0.342
 8             2020                  51         7     0.357
 9             2020                  52         7     0.204
10             2020                  53         4     0.120
# … with 14 more rows
```

Dates should work fine if you set them up correctly.

Comment: Unfortunately this produces the same value for each week, it does not seem to work. The percentage that is calculated corresponds to the whole time period of the dataset.

Comment: it works here. note your data contains less than one week's worth of data

Comment: I ran it again, it still produces the same percentage for each week (my dataset has 22 weeks). The weird thing is that in the outcome, the year is not correct for all weeks (it is 2021 for all weeks, although my dataset starts in 2020).

Comment: but running my exact code as pasted above, you get what I get, right?

Comment: Could you check this: `table( week( your.data$DATETIME ))` . It should show you how many weeks the week function can see from your DATETIME's

Comment: yes, I do get the same result. There seems to be some kind of problem with the number of weeks: 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53 
672 672 672 672 672 672 672 672 672 672 672 672 668 288 288 672 672 672 672 672 672 672 672 192

Comment: Should you be missing the weeks between 14 and 44?

Comment: My dataset comprises of 15 minute values from 01/11/2020 to 04/04/2021. I cannot understand the outcome of the week function. Perhaps there is some problem with my datetime column?

Comment: No, that seems right. 1/11 could be around 44 and 4/4 could be around 14. Could you do a manual calculation from one of the weeks you think is wrong? Fetch the data values for week 45 for example. Calculate the mean difference and compare to the group_by calculation?

Comment: I have calculated manually the percentage error for each week. The problem with the group_by calculation is that it gives the error of the whole 5-month period for each week. Therefore, all the weeks are wrong in the group_by calculation. This is driving me nuts..

Comment: I ran the code with your updated data. Do you not see the same results as I do? I get 0.751 for week 44 an d0.187 for week 45, are those not correct numbers?

Comment: With the manual calculation I get 0.858 for week 44 (only one day:01/11/20) and 0.321 for week 45 (02/11/20 - 08/11/20). With the group_by calculation I get the same for each week.

Comment: AHA. `df %>% filter( week(DATETIME) == 44 ) %>% group_by( week(DATETIME), date(DATETIME) ) %>% summarize( count=n() )`  <- it claims Nov-1st is week 44, same as the following monday. Weeks starting Sun or Mon is confusing the problem!

Comment: Check now - I substituted `week` with `isoweek` (and learned something in the process). `DateCount` in the output lists the number of distinct dates found in the group

Comment: I still get the same number for each week, which is the mean absolute percentage error I get when I calculate manually the whole 5-month period of my dataset...

Comment: silly question, but you didnt forget to put summarise in there?

Comment: I have put summarise in the code. I still think there is something wrong with the datetime column..

Comment: could you upload all of it somewhere?

Comment: Does this work? https://github.com/Argiro1983/dataset.git

Comment: I couldn't access it. how about a pastebin?

Comment: I am sorry, I made the first one private by mistake. Could you please try this one? https://github.com/Argiro1983/data-set.git

Comment: See the updated answer. Perhaps you did not create the dates properly?

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is a problem with the dates. I get: 1: Problem with `mutate()` input `DATETIME`.
i All formats failed to parse. No formats found. Thank you so much, i will try to work my way around it.

Comment: Sorry for coming back, but I cannot get passed the Datetime problem. The format I applied is: format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC", usetz=TRUE. I read that Lubridate will throw that error when attempting to parse dates that do not exist because of daylight savings time. My dataset has one hour less in March indeed (my real tz is EET). Could you let me know what datetime parsing you used and worked? Thank you so much again.

Comment: I used the literal code in my answer. I added `library(magrittr)` just now for the %<>% operator. My _locale_ is en_US.UTF-8 and tz is _UTC_

Comment: Finally, it works!! Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: great! what was the cause of all this headache?

Comment: I made a dataframe before applying your code : DATETIME<-as.POSIXct(df$DATETIME, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="UTC", usetz=TRUE)
df <- data.frame(timestamp = as.POSIXct(DATETIME, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz = "UTC"), input = df[,2:3]). It seems to create problems.